# jQuery AutoComplete - Query Database with JOIN

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm implementing the jQuery autocomplete library on a textbox. The SQL query I have in the back end uses a JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wcc.ItemCode, gwbo.ItemName FROM TBL1 gwbo 
INNER JOIN TBL2 wcc ON gwbo.ItemCode = wcc.ItemCode 
WHERE wcc.ItemCode LIKE '$term%' OR gwbo.ItemName LIKE '%$term%' 
AND wcc.CountStatus != 2 ORDER BY wcc.ItemCode LIMIT 0, 10
```

This takes about 25 seconds to get the autocomplete box to populate and display.. However, when I remove the JOIN and just query 1 table, the autocomplete displays almost immediately (of course the data isn't accurate). Why is my join slowing it down so drastically? I need the join.. Is there a way to speed this up that I am missing, or will I need an entirely new implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) in MySQL to see why the `JOIN` is taking so long, and what indexes you can set up to make this faster.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT wcc.ItemCode, gwbo.ItemName FROM TBL1 gwbo 
INNER JOIN TBL2 wcc ON gwbo.ItemCode = wcc.ItemCode 
WHERE wcc.ItemCode LIKE '$term%' OR gwbo.ItemName LIKE '%$term%' 
AND wcc.CountStatus != 2 ORDER BY wcc.ItemCode LIMIT 0, 10
```

It seems like setting an index on `ItemCode` could speed up your query. I would recommend adding it, and then running the `EXPLAIN` again to see if the db is using the newly created index.

Also, `LIKE` conditions tend to be very slow since no matter what index you set on that column, the db has to do a full-table scan. See if you can change that somehow. Can it be an `==` instead of `LIKE` ?

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out and get back to you. I need the `LIKE` to complete the input for users, e.g. `Mor` input needs to match `Moretti`

Comment: Oh my.. The indexes are being used..and..it works much faster :) THANK YOU